The screen is white for a few seconds when I open the window of my application, written in Python using the "arcade" library
When I run the code it opens the window but there's a white screen for few seconds before the game starts:

How can I fix that? I tried to add time.sleep() because I thought that sprites will load before opening the window but it didn't help.
My code:
from random import shuffle, randint
import arcade
from typing import Callable
import os
import sys


# Код от чат гпт чтобы можно было получить файлы:
def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Получает путь к ресурсам, работает для Dev и для PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller создает временную папку _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)


class TicTacToe(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Создание окна игры
        super().__init__(900, 900, 'Крестики-Нолики')
        arcade.set_background_color(arcade.color.BLACK)

        # Создание и настройка спрайта доски и пустого спрайта
        self.all_sprites = arcade.SpriteList()
        self.none_sprite = arcade.Sprite()
        self.board_sprite = arcade.Sprite(resource_path('board.png'), 0.9)
        self.board_sprite.center_x = 450
        self.board_sprite.center_y = 450
        self.all_sprites.append(self.board_sprite)

        # Создание словаря с координатами для спрайтов крестиков и ноликов
        places = {1: (200, 700), 2: (450, 700), 3: (700, 700),
                  4: (200, 450), 5: (450, 450), 6: (700, 450),
                  7: (200, 200), 8: (450, 200), 9: (700, 200)}

        # Назначение нужных атрибутов
        self.checking_list = None
        self.func_for_bot = lambda none_sprite: self.bot()
        self.cross_sprites = []
        self.zero_sprites = []
        self.players_move = True
        self.game_ended = False

        # Создание спрайтов крестиков и ноликов
        for i in range(1, 10):
            # Создание спрайта крестика
            sprite = arcade.Sprite(resource_path('x.png'), 0.35)
            sprite.center_x, sprite.center_y = places[i]
            sprite.alpha = 0
            self.all_sprites.append(sprite)
            self.cross_sprites.append(sprite)

            # Создание спрайта нолика
            sprite = arcade.Sprite(resource_path('o.png'), 0.4)
            sprite.center_x, sprite.center_y = places[i]
            sprite.alpha = 0
            self.all_sprites.append(sprite)
            self.zero_sprites.append(sprite)

        # Создание поля для игры
        self.field = [[' ', ' ', ' '],
                      [' ', ' ', ' '],
                      [' ', ' ', ' ']]
        self.numbers_field = [[i, i + 1, i + 2] for i in range(1, 10, 3)]
        self.create_checking_list()  # Создание списка для бота


    def check_player_win(self) -> str | None:
        """Проверяет чью-то победу, поражение, или ничью.

         Если выиграл игрок - возвращает строку "The player won!", если выиграл бот - "The bot won!",
         а если ничья - "No one won.". Если ничьи нет и никто не выиграл - возвращается None."""

        # Проверка на ничью
        all_places = [j for i in self.field for j in i]
        for j in self.checking_list:
            i = list(j.values())
            if i.count('X') == 3:
                arcade.schedule(lambda x: arcade.close_window(), 1, self.none_sprite)
                self.game_ended = True
                return 'The player won!'
            elif i.count('O') == 3:
                arcade.schedule(lambda x: arcade.close_window(), 1, self.none_sprite)
                self.game_ended = True
                return 'The bot won!'
        if all_places.count(' ') == 0:
            arcade.schedule(lambda x: arcade.close_window(), 1, self.none_sprite)
            self.game_ended = True
            return 'No one won.'
        # Проверка на чью-то победу

        return None

    def create_checking_list(self) -> None:
        """Создает список словарей для проверки поля ботом"""

        # r - right, l - left, d - diagonal, m - middle, h - horizontal, v - vertical

        # Создание словарей с горизонталями
        top = {(0, i): self.field[0][i] for i in range(3)}
        mh = {(1, i): self.field[1][i] for i in range(3)}
        down = {(2, i): self.field[2][i] for i in range(3)}

        # Создание словарей с вертикалями
        lv = {(i, 0): self.field[i][0] for i in range(3)}
        mv = {(i, 1): self.field[i][1] for i in range(3)}
        rv = {(i, 2): self.field[i][2] for i in range(3)}

        # Создание словарей с диагоналями
        rd = {(2 - i, i): self.field[2 - i][i] for i in range(2, -1, -1)}
        ld = {(i, i): self.field[i][i] for i in range(3)}

        self.checking_list = [top, mh, down, lv, mv, rv, rd, ld]
        shuffle(self.checking_list)  # Добавление случайности в ходы бота

    def bot(self):
        """
        Бот для игры в крестики-нолики. Алгоритм такой:
            1. Проверка возможности выиграть на текущем ходу.
            2. Проверка возможности проиграть на следующем ходу.
            3. Проверка свободности центра.
            4. Если ни одна из вышеперечисленных проверок не удалась, случайный ход.
        """
        arcade.unschedule(self.func_for_bot)  # Отмена дальнейших ненужных повторов функции бота
        made_move = False  # Переменная для проверки, сделан ли ход

        # Проверка возможности выиграть на текущем ходу
        for i in self.checking_list:
            side = list(i.values())
            if side.count('O') == 2 and 'X' not in i.values():
                string = sorted(i.items(), key=lambda obj: obj[1],
                                reverse=True)  # Место без ноликов будет последним
                place = string[-1]
                y, x = place[0]
                self.field[y][x] = 'O'
                made_move = True
                break

        # Если ход не сделан, проверка возможности проиграть на следующем ходу
        if not made_move:
            for i in self.checking_list:
                side = list(i.values())
                if side.count('X') == 2 and 'O' not in i.values():
                    string = sorted(i.items(), key=lambda obj: obj[1],
                                    reverse=True)  # Место без ноликов будет последним
                    place = string[-1]
                    y, x = place[0]
                    self.field[y][x] = 'O'
                    made_move = True
                    break

        # Если ход все еще не сделан, проверка на свободность центра поля
        if not made_move:
            if self.field[1][1] == ' ':
                self.field[1][1] = 'O'
                y, x = 1, 1
                made_move = True

        # Если и сейчас ход не сделан, проверка на свободность углов
            if not made_move:
                corner_indexes = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 0), (2, 2)]
                shuffle(corner_indexes)
                for y, x in corner_indexes:
                    if self.field[y][x] == ' ':
                        self.field[y][x] = 'O'
                        made_move = True
                        break
                else:
                    # Если и центр поля занят, попытка сделать случайный ход
                    for i in self.checking_list:
                        side = list(i.values())
                        if (side.count('X') == 1 and 'O' not in side) or (side.count('O') == 1 and 'X' not in side):
                            string = sorted(i.items(), key=lambda obj: obj[1],
                                            reverse=True)  # Места без ноликов будут последними
                            place = randint(1, 2)
                            y, x = string[place][0]
                            self.field[y][x] = 'O'
                            made_move = True
                            break
                        elif ('X' in side or 'O' in side) and ' ' in side:
                            string = sorted(i.items(), key=lambda obj: obj[1],
                                            reverse=True)  # Место без ноликов будет последним
                            place = string[-1]
                            y, x = place[0]
                            self.field[y][x] = 'O'
                            made_move = True
                            break

        # Если ход все равно не сделан после всех проверок, объявление ничьи
        if not made_move:
            print('No one won.')
            arcade.schedule(lambda x: arcade.close_window(), 1, self.none_sprite)
            self.game_ended = True
        else:
            # Если ход сделан, отображение его в окне игры
            sprite = self.zero_sprites[self.numbers_field[y][x] - 1]
            self.create_checking_list()
            func = lambda delay_time: self.animate_sprite(delay_time, sprite, func)
            arcade.schedule(func, 0.01, sprite)
            self.players_move = True
            print(self.check_player_win())

    @staticmethod
    def animate_sprite(delay_time: float, sprite: arcade.Sprite, schedule_func: Callable[[], None]) -> None:
        """
        Анимирует спрайт. Принимает аргумент delay_time (стандартно от arcade.schedule), спрайт, который необходимо
        анимировать, и функцию, повторение которой нужно отменить при окончании анимации
        """
        if sprite.alpha == 255:  # Если прозрачность максимальная, остановка анимации
            arcade.unschedule(schedule_func)
        else:
            sprite.alpha += 5  # Иначе увеличение прозрачности на 5

    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.start_render()
        self.all_sprites.draw()  # Отрисовка всех видимых спрайтов

    def on_mouse_release(self, x: int, y: int, button: int, modifiers: int):
        # Проверка на нажатие на крестик
        for sprite in self.cross_sprites:
            y1, x1 = (self.cross_sprites.index(sprite) + 3) // 3 - 1, (self.cross_sprites.index(sprite) + 3) % 3  # Координаты на поле, соответствующие номеру клетки
            # Проверка нажатия на спрайт, незанятость поля в месте нажатия, чей сейчас ход и идет ли игра, если все условия выполнены, запуск анимации крестика и размещение крестика во вложенном списке поля.
            if sprite.collides_with_point((x, y)) and self.field[y1][x1] == ' ' and self.players_move and not self.game_ended:
                func = lambda delay_time: self.animate_sprite(delay_time, sprite, func)
                arcade.schedule(func, 0.01, sprite)
                self.field[y1][x1] = 'X'
                self.create_checking_list()
                self.players_move = False
                print(self.check_player_win())
                if not self.game_ended:
                    arcade.schedule(self.func_for_bot, 1.5, self.none_sprite)
                break


# Запуск игры
game = TicTacToe()
arcade.run()

Python version: 3.10
Arcade version: 2.6.17
So, please help me!

What happens if you remove tme.sleep(5)?

IDK maybe you can't change that, my Tauri windows also do this while developing, could be the fault of the library

What's arcade? Is it part of pygame?

@LukeL see tags: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcade "Arcade is a Python library for creating 2D video games."

You code contains lots of insufficient and unrelated data. Can you create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?
